# How to audit deletes in a certain table with Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to record `DELETE` statements in a certain table using Oracle's auditing features.  I ran:

```
SQL> AUDIT DELETE TABLE BY TPMDBO BY ACCESS;

Audit succeeded.
```

I'm unclear if this audits the deletion of a table schema itself (ie, dropping the table), or if it audits the deletion of one or more rows within any table (ie, the delete command).  If the latter, how do I limit this auditing to only a table called `Foo`?  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

```
SQL> show parameter audit

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -------------
audit_file_dest                      string      /backup/audit
audit_sys_operations                 boolean     TRUE
audit_syslog_level                   string
audit_trail                          string      XML, EXTENDED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new feature called fine-grained auditing (FGA), that stores log in SYS.FGA_LOG$ instead SYS.AUD$. Here is the [FGA manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/auditing.htm#CEGBAFIA).

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_FGA.ADD_POLICY(
   object_schema      => 'HR',
   object_name        => 'FOO',
   policy_name        => 'my_policy',
   policy_owner       => 'SEC_MGR',
   enable             =>  TRUE,
   statement_types    => 'DELETE',
   audit_condition    =>  'USER = ''myuser''',
   audit_trail        =>  DBMS_FGA.DB);
END;
/
```

Yes, your original command should audit DELETE operations (not DROP) for this user on all tables. Examine `show parameter audit`

Comment: So with my `AUDIT` command above, does that only audit schema changes?  That would explain why I saw nothing in the audit trail.

Comment: Yes, your original command should audit DELETE operations (not DROP) for this user on all tables. Examine `show parameter audit`

Comment: Added, thanks!  I've actually solved the mystery of the vanishing rows but I'd still like to learn about auditing for my own personal development :)